# Visual Studio ClangFormat format on save not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, clang-format

I set up clangformat and enabled the Format On Save to true.  I press Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D it formats just like I expect.  I undo that change, press Ctrl-S it doesn't format. I build, it doesn't format.  Ctrl+R, Ctrl-D formats the file as I would expect as does Ctrl+R, Ctrl+F.

What did I miss?  I assume it's simple.

Comment: I have the same problem with 2022, either with or without a custom `.clang-format` file. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you are programming in 'non-Microsoft' languages (if you are using clang-format, I assume you want C++), there is no format on save. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72449679/how-to-apply-format-when-saving-in-visual-studio-2022). However, there are free extensions that can apply 'Format Document' on save, which is what you want. See the same post for suggestions.