# How to apply format when saving in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, clang-format

I have placed a `.clang-format` file in my project and can apply the formatting with `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D`. I have also configured and enabled "Run Code Cleanup profile on Save" under `Options -> Text Editor -> Code Cleanup`. But when I save a file, the formatting is not applied.

Is there something I'm missing?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit:** Since it does not seem to be possible for C++ (as of June 2022), I will be using the extension [Format on Save for VS2022](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WinstonFeng.VSFormatOnSave2022) for now, which has a bit more functionality compared to Sedenion's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the free ["Format document on Save"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mynkow.FormatdocumentonSave) extension ([github](https://github.com/Elders/VSE-FormatDocumentOnSave)) to format C++ code via clang-format in Visual Studio 2022 on saving.

Side note, in case anyone else is reading this: In Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 you can also use the Microsoft extension ["Power Commands for Visual Studio"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PowerCommandsforVisualStudio) for this purpose.

Comment: That one works, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, Code Cleanup only applies to C# and VB.Net, and not to C++ code.

From [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022)

> For C# code, you can also configure Visual Studio to apply these code style preferences using the Code Cleanup

---

Edit Oct 13, 2023:

Some of the cleanup functionality (like applying formatting) can be done in VS2022 now for C++ code. It's not as full-fledged as C# though.

Comment: That is indeed unfortunate. Decisions like that always baffle me - clearly implementing this for C++ (or other languages) would require very little extra coding.

Answer (score 4):

vs2022 17.1 supports this feature.

> navigate to Tools > Options > Text Editor > Code Cleanup. Add a check
> in the “Run Code Cleanup profile on Save”

source: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/bringing-code-cleanup-on-save-to-visual-studio-2022-17-1-preview-2/